# Error shared libraries libopencv_xphoto.so.3.1 missing

Tags: linux, opencv, raspberry-pi, computer-vision, openalpr

I'm working on Raspberry Pi Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie).

I have installed

```
  -Tesseract 4.00.00alpha
     - leptonica-1.74.1
          -libjpeg 6b (libjpeg-turbo 1.3.1) : libpng 1.2.50 : libtiff 4.0.3 : zlib 1.2.8
  -OpenCV 2.4.11
```

Installed openalpr but I am not able to use it, only I can do is watch `man alpr`. Any other thing I try to do with this throws an error.
`alpr: error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_xphoto.so.3.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I thought this was because I didn't have `OpenCV3.1.0` installed, but installed it and the error is still there.

This file is inside `/usr/local/lib`, maybe I have to put it somewhere else but I don't know where, or do I have to reinstall Openalpr to get compile all of this from scratch?

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Made it work..

After installing `OpenCV3.1.0` just had to run `sudo ldconfig` command.

And thats all.